# Contact us form displaying admin login page

Tags: wordpress

I have create the contact us form using Gravity Forms Directory plugin. The form is working fine but wp-login.php page header the contact us form is showing 
[image: this my login page]

Any one help me.

Comment: Can you provide a site link for checkup?